# What would the prototype declaration of a C function look like that returns an n-dimensional array?

Tags: c, arrays, function, return

What would the prototype declaration of a C function look like that returns an `n`-dimensional array?

Here, `n>=2`.

Please explain it with dynamic-array/pointers.

My idea is not to pass any-dimensional array.

Please give me 3 examples with `2`, `3` and `4` dimensions.

That will be enough for me to grab the idea.

Comment: In C you cannot return arrays by value, so the question is what is it that you want to do? Are you planning on dynamically allocating a bidimensional array and return the pointer? Do you have a stack allocated array that you want to return? Can you use higher lever abstractions? (your own N-dimensional user defined matrix?)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas the question is not about C++.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I have slightly corrected the comment, but to be honest, the question was originally tagged with [C++] (I know because I filter the list of questions by [C++] tag, **and** I checked by going back in the browser. Still the same basic idea applies

Comment: @Saqib: The question is still valid [C], now the problem is that your question is not clear on the intent not because of the [C++] tag, but because it is not clear. In [C] you still have the same problem: you have not made clear what the intention is, read my first comment and try to describe the actual problem to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest this:

```
array foo();
```

where `array` is an struct defined as:

```
struct array
{
    int *data;
    unsigned int ndim;  //number of dimensions
    unsigned int *size; //size of each dimension is size[i].
};
```

Of course, `data` is just a pointer to `int`, but the other two fields in the struct can be used in such a way that the `data` can be interpreted like an `n` dimensional array, and size of each dimension can be stored in `size` which is yet another pointer.

For example, take 4-dimensional array (dimension size are `10`, `20`, `30` and `40`), then you can create and initialize *4D array* as:

```
unsigned int size[] = {10,20,30,40};
array arr = create(4, size);
```

where `create` function is defined as:

```
array create(unsigned int n, unsigned int *size)
{
    array arr;
    arr.ndim = n;
    arr.size = (unsigned int*) malloc(n * sizeof(unsigned int));
    int i;
    unsigned int totalElements =  1;
    for( i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i) 
    {
          arr.size[i] = size[i]; 
          totalElements *= size[i]; 
    }
    arr.data = (unsigned int*) malloc(totalElements * sizeof(int));
    return arr;
}
```

Of course, you've to work a lot with the fields of the struct, to make it look like n-dimensional array. You don't need to follow me exactly the way I explained, but this is just a basic idea. You can modify it, to suit your specific need.

I would suggest you to write few functions, to manipulate the array, and to access the array elements. I've written `create` function, likewise here is `destroy` function:

```
void destroy(array arr)
{
    if (arr.size != NULL && arr.data != NULL) 
    {
       free(arr.size);
       free(arr.data);
       arr.size = arr.data = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Saqib: This is just one of the many options that you could take, depending on your requirements. To be honest, I have not seen this in production code ever, but that does not mean that I would not do it if I had a problem that fit the solution.

Comment: if you need this industry-approved, you probably don't want to implement this on your own.

Comment: Good idea. You are C++-like using `array` where `struct array` would be appropriate, but it's just a matter of syntax; the logic is good, however. But maybe it would be better to dynamically allocate `size` as well.

Comment: Array lengths should be represented as size_t, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a simple pointer and inside the function allocate memory for an n-dimensional array:

```
int* foo( int nSize )
{
   int*** x;
   x = (int***)malloc( sizeof(int**) * nSize );
   for ( int i = 0 ; i < nSize ; i++ )
   {
      x[i] = (int**)malloc( sizeof(int*) * nSize );
      for ( int j = 0 ; j < nSize ; j++ )
      {
     x[i][j] = ( int* ) malloc(sizeof(int) * nSize );
     for ( int k = 0 ; k < nSize ; k++ )
     {
        x[i][j][k] = i + j+ k;
     }
      }
   }

   return (int*)x;
}
```

Outside the function, since you already know the sizes, you can assume your pointer is of correct size - in this case, a 3-dimensional array:

```
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   int*** x =(int***) foo(4);
   for ( int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ )
      for ( int j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++ )
     for ( int k = 0 ; k < 4 ; k++ )
        cout << x[i][j][k] << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Yes, the casts aren't nice, but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing some detail (like the array's type, whether or not n is passed in as a parameter, whether or not the array is created in the function), so I will try and guess what you mean.

Arrays are referenced by a pointer and an offset. i.e.

```
double a[10];
a[1] = 1.0f;
double *b = &(a[0]);
double c = b[1];
```

Lets assume you want the function to create an array of n elements of type double.

```
double * createArray(int n);
```

There is your function prototype. Your function may look like

```
double * createArray(int n)
{
    double * newarray = new double[n];
    return &(newarray[0]);
}
```

You could use createArray like so

```
double * arrayoftendoubles = createArray(10);
double fifthelement = arrayoftendoubles[4];
```

It is irrelevant what the size of n is.